# Linux mint 19.1 not recognizing dedicated GPU

Tags: linux-mint, thinkpad

I would like to use my Radeon R9 M375 GPU on my [Lenovo Z51-70](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_z41-70_z51-70_ideapad_500_14_15_hmm_201507.pdf)

When I tried 
`$ lspci -v | grep VGA` it gave me this
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])'`

The newest fglrx drivers are installed, but still nothing. Tried to add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.runpm=0"` to /etc/default/grub, like a lot of people said, but still not working.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766344/using-amd-graphics-card-16-04lts shows a lack of support by AMD. However, you may find a solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093585/ubuntu-freezes-and-stop-working-after-update-18-04-problem-graphic-card-amd-ho